# Group table by month

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = pd.read_csv("MLs_Unit_per_day.csv",index_col='Date')



            X1      X2  X3  X4  X5      X6
Date                        
01/01/2023  13  0   20  5   24  14
02/01/2023  13  0   20  5   24  15
03/01/2023  11  0   20  6   24  15
04/01/2023  12  0   20  6   22  16
05/01/2023  11  0   20  6   22  16
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
29/05/2023  13  1   23  6   22  17
30/05/2023  13  1   23  6   22  18
31/05/2023  13  1   23  7   23  18
01/06/2023  12  1   23  7   24  19
02/06/2023  13  0   23  8   24  19
```

I'm trying to group by month ans Sum X1, X2, etc for the hole month. how can I do?
thank you

I tried before without making Date as index with this

```
data.groupby(data['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['RO1'].sum().sort_values()
```

but it show me wrong time format and then wrong months

Comment: is your date column formatted correctly? `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the date to `datetime`, then create a new column for month and finally use `groupby`

```
data = pd.read_csv("MLs_Unit_per_day.csv")
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Create a separate column for year and month
data['YearMonth'] = data['Date'].dt.to_period('M')

monthly_data = data.groupby('YearMonth').sum()

print(monthly_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resample it to month and sum it.

```
monthly_data = df.resample('MS').sum()
```

```
            X1  X2   X3  X4   X5  X6
Date                                
2023-01-01  60   0  100  28  116  76
2023-02-01   0   0    0   0    0   0
2023-03-01   0   0    0   0    0   0
2023-04-01   0   0    0   0    0   0
2023-05-01  39   3   69  19   67  53
2023-06-01  25   1   46  15   48  38
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the `'Date'` column to a DateTime object:

```py
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

You can then use the `pd.Grouper()` function:

```py
monthly_data = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).sum()
```

Let me know how it goes!

**Edit:**
Fixed the formatting issue.

Comment: I tried this, the problem that after 2023-12-01 he is changing date to 2023-01-13 and then I finish with Aug in the summary table

Comment: @NaS Should be a simple fix. Replace the DateTime object conversion line with this one (with the added format attribute):
`data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')`. I edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change anything after loading your data :

```
data.reset_index().assign(Date = lambda df: pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y'))\
  .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')).agg(sum)
```

The `freq='MS'` means month start, you can chose `freq='M'` to indicate the end of month.

Output

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
Date                        
2023-01-01  60  0   100 28  116 76
2023-02-01  0   0   0   0   0   0
2023-03-01  0   0   0   0   0   0
2023-04-01  0   0   0   0   0   0
2023-05-01  39  3   69  19  67  53
2023-06-01  25  1   46  15  48  38
```